# Link changed - where can I find a list of Outlook office REST API scopes?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am currently using the old Outlook office REST API v2 to access outlook.com mail of users via oauth (as opposed to microsoft graph, due to a lack of certain desired features)

For authentication scopes, it needs values like

`https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite`
`https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite.shared`

vs microsoft graph's

`Mail.ReadWrite`
`Mail.ReadWrite.Shared`

Unfortunately, the documentation that supposedly provides a comprehensive list of supported scopes https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/getstarted has had its links changed to point to microsoft graph's documentation (which doesnt really help at all)

> **THE FOLLOWING IS FROM THE ABOVE LINK, AND REDIRECTS TO THE BELOW LINK**
>   scope: a space-delimited list of access scopes that your app requires. For a full list of Outlook scopes, see Authenticate Office APIs using the "v2.0" endpoints [https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/auth_overview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a global list of Outlook scopes but they should be documented along side each REST method under the [Minimum Requires Scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/contacts-rest-operations#GetContacts).